# UIImagePickerController saving file path iOS/iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

Using the below code I am trying to save the video file path only(don't want to run it or open the media player view).

The issue is when I click on the video thumbnail in picker controller, it automatically opens the video in media player view. While I just want to have its path to be save and then I want to use it when the the user will press the play button.

Let me explain a little more, I have 2 views, On MainView I have 2 buttons, 1 button OPEN for opening the `UIImagePickerController` and selecting the video, and 1 button PLAY for playing the same selected video. What I am trying to do here is that, when user clicks on OPEN button `UIImagePickerController` should be opened and user should be able to select the video, when user clicks on video thumbnail `UIImagePickerController` should be dismissed and `MainView` (where open and play buttons are) should be opened. Then if user wants to play the movie, he would click on the PLAY button and watch the movie.

But here in this code, when I click on the movie thumbnail in `UIImagePickerController`, it navigates to the media viewer.

```
- (IBAction)openPicker:(id)sender {

    mediaPickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    NSArray *types = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh];
    mediaPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    mediaPickerController.delegate = self;
    mediaPickerController.mediaTypes = types;
    mediaPickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
    mediaPickerController.delegate = nil; 

   [self presentModalViewController:mediaPickerController animated:YES]; 


}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    videoPath = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSLog(@"videoPath: %@", videoPath);
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two ways ...

1. Set *allowsEditing* to *NO*. This should not display media viewer, but as I don't use UIImagePickerController on a daily basis, I'm not 100 % sure, you need to test it. But even if it works, if video is longer than 10 minutes, editing interface will still be there, because video must be trimmed (look at documentation of UIImagePickerController). But as I wrote, test it, because I can be wrong as I don't use it.
2. Look at [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html). With this class (& friends) you can write your custom picker in a few minutes. Then you can do whatever you want to do. But there's one minor *issue* with this approach - user must agree that your application can access location info, which is quite misleading to users. And that's because assets can contain location info. When user disables access to location info for your application, your custom picker will not work.

---

Update, some code as requested in comment.

Get group list (this code get all groups and filters out groups without videos):

```
if ( ! __assetsLibrary ) {
  __assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
}
[__assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:__assetsGroupType
                               usingBlock:^( ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop ) {
                                 /*
                                  * If group is nil => end of iteration, no more groups will arrive.
                                  */
                                 if ( group ) {
                                   /*
                                    * We do only want groups with videos, so, set filter to allVideos. Following
                                    * numberOfAssets method respects filter settings, so, only number of videos
                                    * is returned.
                                    */
                                   [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];
                                    if ( [group numberOfAssets] > 0 ) {
                                      TMDCONDLOG( DEBUG_PICKER, @"Asset group added: %@", [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName ]);
                                      [__assetsGroups addObject:group];
                                    } else {
                                      TMDCONDLOG( DEBUG_PICKER, @"Skipping %@, no videos inside", [group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] );
                                    }
                                 } else {
                                   // group is nil, no more groups will arrive, reload table
                                   TMDCONDLOG( DEBUG_PICKER, @"Asset groups count: %d", (int)[__assetsGroups count]);
                                   dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                     [self reloadDataFinished];
                                   } );
                                 }
                               }
                             failureBlock:^( NSError *error) {
                               TMDCONDLOG( DEBUG_PICKER, @"Failed: %@", error );
                               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                 [self reloadDataFinished];
                                 [self showAccessFailedError];
                               });
                             }];
```

Here's some code to enumerate `ALAssetsGroup`:

```
[__assetsGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stopEnumeratingAssets ) {
  TMDCONDLOG( DEBUG_ASSETS, @"Asset: %@ Index: %d", result, ( int ) index );
  if ( result  ) {
    [__assets addObject:result];
  }

  /*
   * Enumeration ends? If yes, reload table.
   */
  if ( ! result || index == NSNotFound ) {
    *stopEnumeratingAssets = YES;
    TMDCONDLOG( DEBUG_ASSETS, @"Going to reload table view" );
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTableData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
  }
}];
```

Here's an example how to get number of assets, poster image, etc. for group:

```
__groupAssetsCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%d)", (int) [__assetsGroup numberOfAssets]];    
__groupTitleLabel.text = ( NSString * )[__assetsGroup valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName];
__groupImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[__assetsGroup posterImage]];
```

Use this in your custom `UITableViewCell` for your groups. And here's an example how to get asset thumbnail and duration:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  __assetView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[__asset thumbnail]];
} );
id property = [__asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyDuration];
if ( ! [property isEqual:ALErrorInvalidProperty] ) {
  NSInteger duration = ( ( NSNumber * )property ).integerValue;
  __durationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", ( int ) ( duration / 60 ), ( int ) ( duration % 60 ) ];
} else {
  __durationLabel.text = nil;
}
```

You can use this code in your custom `UITableViewCell` to display 4 assets in a row to emulate Apple's picker UI.

---

Macro examples ...

```
#define TMLOG( __xx, ... ) NSLog( @"%s(%d): " __xx, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__ )

#ifdef DEBUG
#define TMDLOG( __xx, ... ) TMLOG( __xx, ##__VA_ARGS__ )
#else
#define TMDLOG( __xx, ... ) ((void)0)
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG
#define TMDCONDLOG( __cond, __xx, ... ) { \
if ( ( __cond ) )  { \
TMDLOG( __xx, ##__VA_ARGS__ ); \
} \
} ((void)0)
#else
#define TMDCONDLOG( __cond, __xx, ... ) ((void)0)
#endif
```

Comment: Thanx,I have tried the first option, it doesn't work. And second option will not work. As the picker will not be working in location info scenario.

Comment: Will work, but you need to explain it to users. We have custom picker in many apps and no problem so far. If you tell them to enable it, they'll do it. And when your app access assets library for the first time, iOS automatically pops out alert view with question if they agree or not. Don't worry ...

Comment: I am unable to make custom picker, do you have any sample code/tutorial. So that I would get through it

Comment: Added some example code. It's your turn now to get it and implement your custom picker.

Comment: Thank you @Robert, what is DEBUG_PICKER and TMDCONDLOG

Comment: Ignore the whole TMDCONDLOG lines. These are my macros for conditional debugging info. DEBUG_PICKER is simple #define DEBUG_PICKER 0 or 1 to disable / enable debug output.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your

```
openPicker: method.

mediaPickerController.mediaTypes =
    [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```

**Updated**

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{

[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: still it navigates to the media viewer, while I want to dismiss the UIImagePickerController and come back to the main view

Comment: Sorry friend, No resolution :(

Comment: Actually, its UIImagePickerController's functionality that when we try to choose the file, it automatically opens the required viewer.

Comment: What you mean? Have you got the solution?

Comment: No, haven't got the solution. I am looking deep into the UIImagePickerController